# Sorting the rowsum column on a table in r made using addmargins

Tags: r

I have created a table using the code below. I want to sort the row sum column so that it is from high to low with the sum at the bottom.

```
#Some data
DeptEmployees <- data.frame(Department = c("Sales", "Sales", "HR","Sales", "HR", "IT","IT", "HR", "Sales"), Country=c( "USA", "Canada", "UK", "UK", "UK", "USA", "USA", "Canada", "UK"))

#Create the table
DeptTotals<-addmargins(table(DeptEmployees[, c("Department", "Country")]))
DeptTotals
```

I tried unsuccessfully using the below to sort the table, with 5 being the rowsum column:

```
 DeptTotalsReordered<-DeptTotals[order(DeptTotals[,5])]
```

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close. There needs to be a comma after the order statement, since you are rearranging the rows of `DeptTotals`. Also, the structure of the table is such that it is 4x4, with `Department` as a naming column similar to rownames.

`DeptTotalReordered <- DeptTotals[order(DeptTotals[,4]),]`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it allowed me to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work out the answer with help from the post on here. One of the issues I had was that the columnsum row was being re-ordered when I sorted the rowsum column.

```
#Create the table with the rowsum column
DeptTotals<-addmargins(table(DeptEmployees[, c("Department", "Country")]),2)

# Reorder the row sum column so it is descending
DeptTotalReordered <- DeptTotals[order(DeptTotals[,4],decreasing=T),]

# add the sumcolumn row as a final step to ensure it is at the bottom of the table  
DeptTotalReorderedWithColumnSumRow <- addmargins (DeptTotalReordered,1)
DeptTotalReorderedWithColumnSumRow
```